# #1452 error in sql means I can't add foreign key

Tags: sql, database

```
ALTER TABLE Question ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SessionQuestion FOREIGN KEY
(SessionId) REFERENCES Session (SessionId);
```

SQL above gives me error below:

> *#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mobile_app`.`#sql-567_20be3`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SessionQuestion`
>
>    FOREIGN KEY (`SessionId`) REFERENCES `Session` (`SessionId`))*

I want to include a foreign key in `Question` table to link up with `SessionId` but why won't it let me and how can it be fixed?

`Question` table:

```
SessionId(PK) QuestionId(PK) QuestionContent
--------------------------------------------
1             1              What is 2+2
1             2              What is 3+3
2             1              What is 5+5
2             2              What is 4+7
```

`Session` table:

```
SessionId SessionName
---------------------
1         AAA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question table includes `SessionId`s that are not found in the session table (well, actually, just one: `2`). The `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, however, requires every `SessionId` used in the question table to exist in the session table *by its definition*.

Either insert all missing sessions, or remove all questions that reference sessions that don't exist.

---

To get a list of all `SessionId`s you're missing in the table `Session`, you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Question.SessionId
FROM Question
     LEFT JOIN Session
       ON Question.SessionId = Session.SessionId
WHERE Session.SessionId IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful, is there a query where I am able to see if sessionId is in Session Table but not in Question Table?

Comment: @Manixman: You want the other way around. All SessionIDs that are in `Question` and not in `Session`: `SELECT DISTINCT SessionID FROM Question WHERE SessionID NOT IN (SELECT SessionID FROM Session) ;` For the FK to be defined, this query should return no rows.

Comment: @ypercube: a `LEFT JOIN` is also an option, as used in my updated answer.

Comment: @TInctorius Of course. There are 3 (common) ways for this type of query, using `NOT IN`, using `NOT EXISTS` and using `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`. You already have my +1.